# Mongo 3.2 -> Mongo 3.4 Collation

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I'm trying to update a server running MongoDB 3.2 to MongoDB 3.4. I have wildcard text indexes on the collections, which caused the upgrade to not work. An illustrative example of an index on the 3.2 instance is:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "name" : "$**_text",
    "ns" : "mydatabase.mycollection",
    "collation" : {
        "strength" : 1
    },
    "weights" : {
        "$**" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "english",
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
}
```

I dug in and did some research and found this in the MongoDB 3.4 docs.

> The collation option is available for all index types except for text
>   indexes.

... and so the problem is the old index had a collation in it:

```
"collation" : {
    "strength" : 1
},
```

... which was intended to make search case-insensitive. Maybe this was invalid in MongoDB 3.2 as well and wasn't actually doing anything? But MongoDB 3.4 has stricter validation of indexes. I guess the way to do this in Mongo 3.4 is to apply the collation to the collection rather than the index.

How do you do this on a collection that already exists (as opposed to as an option for createCollection)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got no traction from this post, and decided it was relatively straightforward to export the data and write a script to reconstitute the database in a fresh install of Mongo in my case, but if I had a lot more data or many more collections and indexes, I would imagine this would be a hard pill to swallow.